# Illegal Instruction when running Chroma db route

Tags: azure-container-instances, telemetry, chromadb

I have an application that runs on an azure container, the build happens just fine through GitHub Workflow, I get to install chroma and hnswlib without any issue. However, when I hit any routes that use Chroma db, I get this error.

```
Using small model
Loading content from folder std...
Embedding documents: 100%|██████████| 10/10 [00:11<00:00,  1.12s/it]
INFO:chromadb.telemetry.posthog:Anonymized telemetry enabled. See https://docs.trychroma.com/telemetry for more information.
Illegal instruction
```

The Chroma docs say I have to rebuild in the Azure environment, I am not sure how to go about this because I'm new to both Azure ACIs and Chroma db.
Has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: the "Illegal instruction" error you're encountering strongly suggests a compatibility issue between the pre-built Chroma binaries and the Azure container environment.  (e.g., x86-64, ARM) have different instruction sets. Pre-built binaries are compiled for specific architectures. If your build environment's architecture differs from your Azure container's, you'll likely get "Illegal instruction" errors.